# How to use wordnet to find semantic relation between two web pages?

Tags: python, nlp, wordnet

I want some way to determine whether two web pages are semantically related.I googled and found something called as the WordNet (a large lexical database). I want to know that how can I accomplish this using python and WordNet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and crudest way to do this would be:

1. extract top N terms (keywords) from each page (could be as simple as top N terms by frequency, excluding stop words such as 'a, the, an' in English). This will give you a feature set for each page.
2. Compare top terms between pages for overlaps. You could use Wordnet to compare synonyms of your terms e.g. sneakers <==> trainers. If you have some degree of keyword overlap then pages are in some way related.

EDIT:

A better way to derive a feature set of keywords for each page would be to extract statistically significant words for each page. You can do this by acquiring or compiling a list of (1 2 and 3 word)  [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) from a reference text e.g. wikipedia) and then computing the n-grams for the words/phrases on your page and comparing the frequency of occurrence of your n-grams with that of those in  the global n-gram set. If you find you have n-grams on your page that occur more frequently than what you would expect given the reference corpus then they are likley to be statistically significant for that page.

The hard part in this is acquiring or compiling  the reference n-gram (it needs to be big enough to be statistically viable) which you ned to compare with the n-grams on your webpages. You can acquire google's n-gram corpus, or possibly build your own by looking at freely available to download websites like wikipedia. Others may have published a freely available n-gram set if you look around on google.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it much personally, but I've heard that the [NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit)](http://www.nltk.org/) library can be a great help for these kinds of language analysis tasks. They have a lot of nice documentation and tutorials online, in addition to plenty of language corpora and other datasets to get you started.